# Заставить парсер выдать информацию внутри тега category

Tags: android, java

Доброго времени суток!

Вопрос такой:
вот пример RSS ленты

```
<category domain="http://samplesite.com/world/russia/">
<![CDATA[ Россия ]]>
</category>
```

Как мне заставить парсер выдать инфу внутри тега `<category "####">` , а не между начальным и конечным тегами?

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, особенностей андройдов, но в java это легко делается через xml парсер.
Например, как здесь: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/